# How to retrieve bill information for a check in Quickbooks 

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

I want to get the list of all the bills for which a particular check has been generated.

Consider I have 2 grids on a form. 1st grid (`gridChecks`) displays all the checks in Quickbooks and when user selects a check, all the bills that are linked to that check should be displayed in the second grid i.e. `gridBills` which will have columns `Date, Type, ReferenceNumber, OriginalAmount, Balance, Paid Amount`.

I am not able to find how to use `IBillPaymentCheckRet` or which interface to use and how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bills to which a check has been applied are referenced in the `AppliedToTxnRet` element (`QBFC: AppliedToTxnRetList`). In order to populate this element you'll have to specify it in the `IncludeRetElement` list for your `BillPaymentCheck` query request.